# C++ Optimizing If Statements

Tags: c++, optimization

Consider following statement:

```
 C a, b; //C contains c1, c2 and c3 all integers

if(a.c1==b.c1 && a.c2 == b.c2) {
     a.c3=b.c3;
 }
```

Will this statement be optimized to the following:

```
 if(a.c1 == b.c1) {
    if(a.c2 == b.c2) {
       a.c3=b.c3;
    }
 }
```

AFAIK, C++ compilers does not perform this kind of operation since it can have side effects. But these are built-in types.

- Is there anything related in the standard?
- If it is compiler specific is main stream compilers (MS, GNU, Intel) are doing it or not?

Comment: The language is in fact *required* to perform that "optimization".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The following code snippet:

```
C a, b; //C contains c1, c2 and c3 all integers
if(a.c1==b.c1 && a.c2 == b.c2)
{
    a.c3=b.c3;
}
```

will be "optimized" to this (or something equivalent):

```
if(a.c1 == b.c1)
{
    if(a.c2 == b.c2)
    {
        a.c3=b.c3
    }
}
```

This is required not because of optimization but because the C++ standard *requires* [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So reasonably standards-conforming C++ compilers should be able to short-circuit that.

There isn't a single place in the C++ standard that explicitly states that some boolean operators are short-circuited. It is implied from the rules:

> **ISO/IEC C++ Standard 14882 §5.14 Logical AND operator [expr.log.and]**
>
> ```
> logical-and-expression:
>     inclusive-or-expression
>     logical-and-expression && inclusive-or-expression
> ```
>
> 1. The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>      implicitly converted to type `bool` (clause 4). The result is `true` if
>      both operands are `true` and `false` otherwise. **Unlike `&`, `&&`
>      guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not
>      evaluated if the first operand is `false`.**

The rules are similar for the `||` operator:

> **ISO/IEC C++ Standard 14882 §5.15 Logical OR operator [expr.log.or]**
>
> ```
> logical-or-expression:
>     logical-and-expression
>     logical-or-expression || logical-and-expression
> ```
>
> 1. The `||` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both
>      implicitly converted to `bool` (clause 4). It returns `true` if either
>      of its operands is `true`, and `false` otherwise. **Unlike `|`, `||`
>      guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is
>      not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to `true`.**

And the conditional `?` operator:

> **ISO/IEC C++ Standard 14882 §5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]**
>       conditional-expression:
>           logical-or-expression
>           logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression
>
> 1. Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression
>      is implicitly converted to `bool` (clause 4). It is evaluated and if
>      it is `true`, the result of the conditional expression is the value of
>      the second expression, otherwise that of the third expression. All
>      side effects of the first expression except for destruction of
>      temporaries (12.2) happen before the second or third expression is
>      evaluated. **Only one of the second and third expressions is
>      evaluated.**

Answer (score 3):

Standard 5.14 / 1 :

The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both implicitly converted to type  bool (clause 4).
The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right
evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.**

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses [shirt-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So, in a way it will work that way.

I doesn't actually evaluate and optimize the code that way, but it will evaluate to the equivalent in assembly code.

Comment: I really wanted *shirt*-circuit evaluation to be something.

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is short-circuiting.  In other words, if a.c1 == b.c1 fails to evaluate to true, then a.c2 == b.c2 won't even be evaluated.

It is similar to the solution you describe, but it is part of the C++ language (and seems much easier to read than explicitly typing nested if statements).